# Rename the "Terminal" app in OSX

Tags: terminal

Is there any way to rename the Terminal app?

When I try to rename it by right-clicking it, that option is greyed out.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? This smacks so much of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: open it, edit the info.plist, but ^ why would you even want to do that? I can understand renaming google chrome to, ram monster, but I see no reason for renaming the terminal app, do you just want to hide it?

Comment: Would creating an alias or symbolic link with another name work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Apple doesn't allow user to rename any app that comes with the O/S

Comment: Yes they do, just not via Finder.

Comment: Part of the job of any responsible IT person (which I am) is to discourage people from doing things to their computers that might possibly screw things up. Sure if you want to turn off SIP, rename it in a command line and then turn SIP back on again. Yes that works. But Apple makes it difficult to do this *for a reason.* To keep people with good intentions from doing things to their computer that might break it.